# Jenkins jobs takes too long, occasionally

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-job-dsl

We are running Jenkins 2.303.1 deployed in an EKS cluster via helm, and occasionally some jobs are taking way too long. This is arbitrary, at one point in time the job can take 15 min, the next day - 2 hours, without reconfiguring anything - and the next day again 15 min and so on...
When checking the resource allocations it looks like the job not using enough cpu utilization, around 200 milicores (each job opens up as a pod) and maybe that's the issue?

I've checked almost everything I could think of - jobs resources, nodes resources (issue happens also when there is a single job running), and couldn't find anything in the monitoring plugin also. Any ideas what can cause this arbitrary slowdown?
The pipeline setup looks like this:

```
pipeline {
        agent {
            kubernetes {
                yaml """
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  labels:
    jenkins: slave
    app: platform
spec:
  spec:
    affinity:
      podAntiAffinity:
        requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
        - labelSelector:
            matchExpressions:
            - key: app
              operator: In
              values:
              - platform
          topologyKey: "kubernetes.io/hostname"
  containers:
  - name: ruby
    image: <our custom ruby image>
    command:
    - cat
    tty: true
    resources:
      requests:
        cpu: 6
        memory: 12Gi
  - name: mysql
    image: mysql:5.6
    resources:
      requests:
        cpu: 2
        memory: 6Gi
    env:
    - name: MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
      value: mypass
    - name: MYSQL_USER
      value: admin
    - name: MYSQL_PASSWORD
      value: mypass

  - name: redis
    image: redis:3.0

  - name: docker
    image: docker:19.03.1
    command:
    - sleep
    args:
    - 99d
    env:
    - name: DOCKER_HOST
      value: tcp://localhost:2375

  - name: docker-daemon
    image: docker:19.03.1-dind
    securityContext:
      privileged: true
    env:
      - name: DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR
        value: ''
"""
            }
        }
        options {
            disableConcurrentBuilds()
            timestamps()
            timeout(time: 4, unit: 'HOURS')
            buildDiscarder(logRotator(numToKeepStr: '10'))
            ansiColor('xterm')
            quietPeriod 30
        }
```

Its a pretty basic NodeJS CI/CD pipeline. After monitoring closely - when job is running ok the CPU utilization is around 3-4 cores, when the job is stuck is stays on 100 milicores (sounds legit), and it dosent matter what stage is running, even the first 'setup pipeline' stage utilizes a small number of CPU hence takes forever to run.

Highly appreciate!

Comment: What is the job actually doing?

Comment: Its a pretty basic NodeJS CI/CD pipeline. After monitoring closely - when job is running ok the CPU utilization is around 3-4 cores, when the job is stuck is stays on 100 milicores (sounds legit), and it dosent matter what stage is running, even the first 'setup pipeline' stage utilizes a small number of CPU hence takes forever to run.

```

Comment: Did you manage to figure it out? Currently having a similar issue with docker building where it took over 7 minutes on the become root step.
And it's not consistent either.